# vertical align html form

Tags: html, css

I'm looking to center this textbox and submit button on the page both vertically and horizontally but the following code just puts it in the top center. How can I center this to the page? It's like it's ignoring the vertical-align setting.

```
<div style="text-align:center; vertical-align:middle">
    <form action="save_thought.php" method="post">
        <input type="text" name="thought"><br>
        <input type="submit" value="Submit">
    </form>
</div>
```

Comment: You may read this article discussing recent css vertical centering thechniques: http://blog.themeforest.net/tutorials/vertical-centering-with-css/

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can use `position:absolute` DEMO http://jsfiddle.net/kevinPHPkevin/U8dZr/

```
div#form-wrapper {
    position:absolute;
    top:50%;
    right:0;
    left:0;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

You can also go for this:

**HTML**

```
<div id="main" >
   <form id="frm" action="save_thought.php" method="post">
      <input type="text" name="thought"><br>
      <input type="submit" value="Submit">
   </form>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
#main
{
  line-height: 400px;
  text-align:center; 
  vertical-align:middle;
}

#frm
{
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: middle;
  line-height: 14px; 
}
```

[**Demo Here**](http://jsfiddle.net/U8dZr/2/)

Answer (score 3):

None of the solutions provided above worked for me for my real proyect in which I wanted to center both vertically and horizontally a form inside a div (not taking as reference the full page) but I got it using `display: flex;` property. Just display your parent `div` as `flex` and then use the property `margin: auto;` for your child `form`.

In your case, it would be like this:

**HTML** code:

```
<div id="centeringDiv" style="display: flex;">
    <form id="mainForm" action="save_thought.php" method="post">
        <input type="text" name="thought"><br>
        <input type="submit" value="Submit">
    </form>
</div>
```

**CSS** code:

```
html, body{
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  margin: 0;
}

#centeringDiv{
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  display: flex;
}

#mainForm{
  margin: auto;
}
```

[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/3q9cswse/) in which you can see that the form it is being centered both vertically and horizontally in the full page.

Answer (score 0):

CSS will probably never stop to amaze me. Given Dhaval Marthak's answer I was actually able to achieve what I wanted, right aligned labels and left aligned fields (on the right of the labels of course):

```
label {
    display: block;
    position:relative;
    text-align: right;
    width: 100px;
    margin: 0 0 5px 0;
}
label > input,
label > select,
input {
    position: absolute;
    left: 120px;
}
```

The [JSfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/qh8kzez9/) still points out my remaining problem, the field will align with the *bottom* of the label if the label breaks the line. But I am sure that can be amended as well.

Of course it would also be nice if the space between labels and fields could be assigned more "dynamically" based on the sizes of the labels (e.g. in different languages) but I have not seen this done anywhere so far. I guess I will have to resort to tables if I really need it.

Answer (score 0):

You have have to change the width from "100%" to "px" and then you have to do margin: "auto".

Then the form will be centered horizontally.