# Having trouble vertical aligning items in Bootstrap 4

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4

I know this is a question that has a number of threads on here however after trying several of the suggested answers I am having no such luck.

I am not new to programming however I am new to CSS and HTML.

Currently I am trying to create a basic "Login Page" for my personal web application.

GitHub: https://github.com/n-winspear/cashflow-webapp

From reading other threads on here I have tried:
- Adding heights to columns, rows and containers.
- Changing the container type
- Using many different classes (center-text, justify-content-center, align-self-center, align-items-center)
- Changing the form type
- Loading the CSS directly from a URL instead of a local file

```java
<div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="form-row align-items-center">
        <div class="col-sm-4 offset-sm-4">
        <form class="form-signin">
            <div class="form-group">
            <label for="exampleInputEmail1">Email address</label>
            <input type="email" class="form-control" id="exampleInputEmail1" aria-describedby="emailHelp" placeholder="Enter email">
            <small id="emailHelp" class="form-text text-muted">We'll never share your email with anyone else.</small>
        </div>
                <div class="form-group">
            <label for="exampleInputPassword1">Password</label>
            <input type="password" class="form-control" id="exampleInputPassword1" placeholder="Password">
        </div>
        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Submit</button> 
        </form>
    </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

What I was hoping to get was the form sitting in the middle of the web page however it stays stuck at the top.

Here is what I am currently getting
[image: what it looks like]

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/kevinPHPkevin/U8dZr/

Comment: Possible duplicate of [vertical align html form](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16626240/vertical-align-html-form)

Comment: I have tried vertical align html form before and no such luck

Comment: clear your cache, it's working here http://jsfiddle.net/kevinPHPkevin/U8dZr/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i cloned your project and made some modifications on it, and it works well, so what you must do is:

1. create a style.css file in your css folder (much cleaner code)
2. add a link to your new stylesheet in html and add an id to your container so that you can identify it (in case if you are going to add other containers later,you will need to add an id), so your final html code will look like that:

   ```
   <!-- Bootstrap CSS -->
       <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="bootstrap/css/bootstrap.css">
       <link rel="stylesheet" type"text/css" href="bootstrap/css/styles.css">

       <title>Cashflow Web App</title>
   </head>
   <body>
       <div class="container-fluid" id="main-block">
           <div class="form-row align-items-center">
               <div class="col-sm-4 offset-sm-4">
                   <form class="form-signin">
                       <div class="form-group">
                           <label for="exampleInputEmail1">Email address</label>
                           <input type="email" class="form-control" id="exampleInputEmail1" aria-describedby="emailHelp" placeholder="Enter email">
                           <small id="emailHelp" class="form-text text-muted">We'll never share your email with anyone else.</small>
                       </div>
                       <div class="form-group">
                           <label for="exampleInputPassword1">Password</label>
                           <input type="password" class="form-control" id="exampleInputPassword1" placeholder="Password">
                       </div>
                       <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Submit</button> 
                   </form>
               </div>
            </div>
       </div>

       <!-- JavaScript -->
       <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-q8i/X+965DzO0rT7abK41JStQIAqVgRVzpbzo5smXKp4YfRvH+8abtTE1Pi6jizo" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
       <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.7/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-UO2eT0CpHqdSJQ6hJty5KVphtPhzWj9WO1clHTMGa3JDZwrnQq4sF86dIHNDz0W1" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
       <script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-JjSmVgyd0p3pXB1rRibZUAYoIIy6OrQ6VrjIEaFf/nJGzIxFDsf4x0xIM+B07jRM" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
   </body>
   ```
3. in style.css file, use display:table and display: table-cell, simply write the following code:

   ```
   body{
     height: 100%;
   }
   #main-block{
      height: 100%;
      display: table;
   }

   .align-items-center{
      display: table-cell;
      vertical-align: middle;
   }
   ```

Here's how it looked after i added these modifications, i hope this helps you.[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SYF49.png)

feel free to ask any other question if it doesn't work for you.

Comment: This is perfect thank you so much. One question I do have is why have you commented out "main-block"?

Comment: i'm glad i could help you, "main-block" is just an id that i created to identify your container, so when i use this id (main-block) in css, the style will be applyed only on the div with that id, so if your html page have only these elements id wouldn't be very usefull, but if you add other elements later, ID will help you to better identify your elements.
But after all, it's just a choice, you can use other css selectors, it would work too.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the absolute position trick to vertically center the div, or use Flex on the body container and VH units. In this case I would go with the absolute position.

Absolute:

```
.container-fluid {
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  transform: translateY(-50%);
}
```

Flex Body:

```
body {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  height: 100vh;
}
```

Comment: I have tried both of these, or at lease I believe I have done it correctly however not such luck. Ive added in my git hub page that has the code incase you need to look at it.

Comment: I don't see any custom styles in the git, just Bootstrap's stylesheet. Put this in the <head> tag of your page: `<style>.container-fluid {
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  transform: translateY(-50%);
}</style>`

This is not ideal, you would wan't a custom stylesheet but this should at least show you results on your page.